# How can I do a ngModel in a loop?

Tags: angular, loops, ngmodel

I have an issue in my angular application I want to change the value of ngModel if the item is in the license but I'm in a loop in my .ts file I think the ngModel take the last value of test but some items are not in the license I want to put the value of ngModel to false.

.html file :

```
<div *ngFor="let elt of element">

    <input type="checkbox" #checkbox class="input_checkbox" [ngModel]="test" name="itemBoolean_{{elt.item.id}}" id="custom_item_{{elt.item.id}}" >

</div>
```

.ts file :

```
 element : item[];

 itemInLicense : ItemLicense[];

 test : boolean = false ;


ngOnInit() {

    this.itemInLicense.forEach((elt)=>{

        if(document.getElementById("custom_item_"+elt.itemId))

            this.test = true ;

        else

            this.test = false ;

     })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index` number in the iteration if the variable you bind is an `Array` as well:

**Then you need to change property `test` as follows:**

```
 test : boolean[] = [] ;

 ngOnInit() {

   this.itemInLicense.forEach((elt, index)=>{
     if(document.getElementById("custom_item_"+elt.itemId)){
       this.test[index] = true ;
    } else {
      this.test[index] = false ;
    });
 }
```

**And adapt the HTML as here:**

```
<div *ngFor="let elt of element; i=index">
  <input type="checkbox" 
         #checkbox 
         class="input_checkbox"
         [ngModel]="test[i]"
         name="itemBoolean_{{elt.item.id}}"
         id="custom_item_{{elt.item.id}}" >

</div>
```

Comment: Ok i think it work but I have a loop issue to resolve.

Comment: OK @Soleyne completed the examplebut still unclear where `element` gets it's value

Comment: Element is a json answer from my api